# Can i deploy my Java Spring-Boot Application in my Synology NAS?

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, deployment, synology

I have a Spring-Boot Application with REST API (Maven build and MongoDB Database). I will also make a UI with Angular 2 on top of that (npm build).

What i would like to do is, to host this site, with its backend & database on a server. Can i do that on my Synology NAS (DS216j)? Or should i better buy a small computer like Raspberry Pi 3?

I have heard somewhere that we can deploy our apps in Docker, and Synology has a docker app or sth? Will this help me reaching my goal? I would like to have a step by step guide from your similar setups.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, you only want to get your app running on your NAS, so using Docker would be an option, but no requirement.

According to the [model-specific download page](https://www.synology.com/en-global/support/download/DS216j#packages), your DS216j supports Java8.
So what you have to do:

1. Install Java on your NAS
2. Package your application as standalone jar-file: If not yet done, you can do that in your pom.xml (see [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) for details; btw, this standalone mode is one of the best features of Spring Boot)
3. Now you can upload the jar-file
4. Run it via the [command line](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/system_terminal) with `java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar`

Just make sure that the port of your app does not conflict with the ports used by your NAS.

You could also create a Docker image from your app and run it on your NAS, it seems like your model supports Docker: https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/packages/Docker. But that would create some extra effort, but no added value, from my point of view.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Looks promising. And do you know how i can deploy my angular app (UI) ?

Comment: You can package and deploy Spring Boot app and GUI in one single jar. The following post explains how to setup a project from the scratch. See also some of the comments, there it is discussed in detail that both components are packaged in one single jar. https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/#comment-290734

Comment: i am very sorry, i forgot to mention that, my backend uses a MongoDB database.. do you somehow know whether i still can handle it without Docker? Quick google search with MongoDB results in answers where Docker is mentioned..

Comment: by the way.. my Synology model is not supported :/  I think this is the dead end for my question. Thank you though!

Comment: Ok, sorry to hear that. Depending on your requirements, you could move to a database like MySQL or MariaDB (which is natively supported by Synology, in case you want to avoid buying new hardware).